# Is there any way to setup a VS2010 configuration for one click remote debugging?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010

Right now I am doing the following:
1) build
2) copy build config target dir to other computer (VS remote debug monitor already stated)
3) RDP to launch recently built debug exe
4) click Debug -> Attach to process, select process from other machine
5) debug, make a change, goto 1.

What I would like to do is:
1) press F5 and debug

Am I missing an obvious way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there's a way.  For detailed steps, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8x6by8d2.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VC.PROJECT.IVCREMOTEDEBUGPAGEOBJECT.ATTACH%29&rd=true

Quick summary is that you need to install msvcmon and setup file share on the remote computer.  You need to make sure your linker output is on the file share that is accessible by the remote computer.

Back to the local computer, in the Solution Explorer window, right click your project, select Configuration Properties -> Debugging.  Choose "Remote Windows Debugger" in "Debugger to Launch" dropdown.  Fill in the grids below, and you're good to go.  An F5 will build and run your program remotely while debugging locally.